# How to stop the user from highlighting any text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, highlight

There is a method to do it with CSS, but it is a non-standard feature:

```
::selection {
    background: transparent;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Is there a way to do it in JavaScript? More on `::selection` can be found at [**caniuse**](http://caniuse.com/#search=::selection).

Comment: I certainly hope not!

Comment: You're trying to use JavaScript as a polyfill for this CSS feature?  Or you need to know how to update CSS for elements with JavaScript?

Comment: I guess my question isn't clear sorry about that. I want to know how to use JavaScript to achieve the same effect i.e. stop the user from highlighting the text.

Comment: @Brad I think he wants a javascript method because his CSS method isn't support on all browsers. Mostly mobile ones.

Comment: @Danny Yes that is exactly what I want to find out.

Comment: I know the post I marked duplicate of is titled "CSS" but there are JavaScript solutions discussed in the answers there.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 That is not a duplicate at all.  Marking something as a duplicate requires that the questions are the same, not that they have the same answers.

Comment: Your css solution still allows the selection of text it just makes the background of the selected text transparent. Is that what you want or do you want the selection of text to be disabled completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can listen for the [onselectstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536969(v=vs.85).aspx) event and cancel it. [Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/fewegesi/1/edit).

Comment: Out of curiosity, you can see that if you highlight the "This is text you can" in your example, starting from the end. You can scroll up and highlight the un-highlightable text. Is there a way to prevent that or would you just have to apply the onselectstart to the whole page?

Comment: You would use onselectstart with the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want a js solution, but this css style should work for all main browsers:

```
.nohighlight{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
function disableSelection(target){
    if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") // IE
        target.onselectstart=function(){return false;};
    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") // Firefox
        target.style.MozUserSelect="none";
    else // Opera and the others
        target.onmousedown=function(){return false;};
    target.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

Usage :

```
disableSelection(document.body);
```

Working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/jocuhiwu/2/edit?html,js,output)